# Sort by dynamic field in go lang

Tags: sorting, go

So I'm struggling to figure out how to sort following structure by "status" field (asc, desc)

```
type CampaignStatus struct {
    Campaign CampaignData
    Status   string `json:"status" bson:"status"`
}

type CampaignsPagination struct {
    Pagination PageMetadata  `json:"pagination"`
    Campaigns  []CampaignStatus `json:"campaigns"`
}
```

Example json of full campaigns pagination:

```
   "pagination": {
        "page": 1,
        "per_page": 15,
        "page_count": 1,
        "total_count": 4
    },
    "campaigns": [
        {
            "Campaign": {
                "_id": "57597fc6799e0fe41d0eede6",
                "name": "Test campaign",
                "description": "Just test campaign"
                "isEmail": true
            },
            "status": "expired"
        },
        ...
    }
```

So my function is retuting variable ret := &CampaignsPagination{} which is filled with data from mongoDB but status is determinated by other stuff in realtime. So reflect package is saying that I'm trying to sort type of *CampaignsPagination and everything what I use pretty much ends with errors like "type CampaignsPagination does not support indexing" (using sort packag) any hints are more then welcome

Update:

How I try to sort this (but it won't compile due to (type *CampaignsPagination does not support indexing

```
func (a *CampaignsPagination) Len() int {
    return len(a)
}
func (a *CampaignsPagination) Swap(i, j int) {
    a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
}
func (a *CampaignsPagination) Less(i, j int) bool {
    if a[i].Status < a[j].Status {
        return true
    }
    if a[i].Status > a[j].Status {
        return false
    }
    return a[i].Status < a[j].Status
}
```

Comment: Please post your code how you try to sort them.

Comment: Of course you cannot sort CampaingPagination as this is not a slice. Apply Sort to Campaigns after wrapping in in type which provides the sort.Interface methods comparing the Status.

Comment: @icza I added how I try to sort them. Volker any hints how can I wrap this into correct type then ?

Comment: By what field would you want to sort and do your son files reflect the structure of your JSON 1:1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually sorting is defined on a slice. You try to define sorting on your `CampaignsPagination` struct type.

This can also be done, but it's a little unusal (e.g. what would you do if you decide you want to have another order based on another field?). Since your receiver `a` is not a slice but a (pointer to a) wrapper struct, when indexing and returning the length, use the slice `a.Campaigns`. Also `string` values are comparable and ordered (lexically byte-wise). So you can simply compare `CampaignStatus.Status` values and return the result in `Less()`.

```
func (a *CampaignsPagination) Len() int {
    return len(a.Campaigns)
}
func (a *CampaignsPagination) Swap(i, j int) {
    a.Campaigns[i], a.Campaigns[j] = a.Campaigns[j], a.Campaigns[i]
}
func (a *CampaignsPagination) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return a.Campaigns[i].Status < a.Campaigns[j].Status
}
```

A more logical solution would be to define the sorting on a slice, e.g.:

```
type CampaignStatusSort []CampaignStatus

func (c CampaignStatusSort) Len() int { return len(c) }

func (c CampaignStatusSort) Swap(i, j int) { c[i], c[j] = c[j], c[i] }

func (c CampaignStatusSort) Less(i, j int) bool { return c[i].Status < c[j].Status }
```

And then if you have a value of type `*CampaignsPagination`, you can sort the campaigns like this:

```
cp := &CampaignsPagination{} // Init struct

sort.Sort(CampaignStatusSort(cp.Campaigns))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, great!

Answer (score 0):

There is no one to one relationship between `CampaignsPagination` and `Status`. `CampaignsPagination` has a slice of `CampaignStatus` as a field; means `CampaignsPagination` has many `Status`es.

So I assume that you want to sort the field `Campaigns []CampaignStatus`. Your code is almost correct; for `CampaignsPagination` to implement the interface `sort.Interface`:

```
func (x *CampaignsPagination) Len() int {
    return len(x.Campaigns)
}
func (x *CampaignsPagination) Swap(i, j int) {
    a := x.Campaigns
    a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
}
func (x *CampaignsPagination) Less(i, j int) bool {
    a := x.Campaigns
    if a[i].Status < a[j].Status {
        return true
    }
    if a[i].Status > a[j].Status {
        return false
    }
    return a[i].Status < a[j].Status
}
```

But it would be more logical to introduce a sortable type:

```
type Statuses []CampaignStatus

func (a Statuses) Len() int {
    return len(a)
}
func (a Statuses) Swap(i, j int) {
    a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
}
func (a Statuses) Less(i, j int) bool {
    if a[i].Status < a[j].Status {
        return true
    }
    if a[i].Status > a[j].Status {
        return false
    }
    return a[i].Status < a[j].Status
}
```

And then use this as the field `Campaigns`:

```
type CampaignsPagination struct {
    Pagination PageMetadata `json:"pagination"`
    Campaigns  Statuses     `json:"campaigns"`
}
```